# What is the purpose of the _daemon directive in fail2ban?

Tags: fail2ban

A number of the filters that come with `fail2ban` have a `_daemon` directive, but there is no mention of it in the [documentation](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8) and no reference to it in any of my jail definitions.

What's it for?

Comment: About 60s after asking this, I realized what the answer was likely to be and it turned out to be so :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `daemon` directive is used to construct the `__prefix_line` regular expression that many of these filters use.

It allows the filter to ignore lines that come from other services, but may otherwise match your regular expression.

You can see references to `_daemon` in the `filter.d/common.conf` file.